# Construction of mollifiers to generate a desire function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I am currently reading a book on analysis but do not understand the following:

It claims that we can construct a function $\phi: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

$1.$  $\quad $ $\phi \in C^2$ and has bounded derivatives (including itself) up to second order.

$2.$  $\quad $ $\phi (y) = \frac{1}{|y|}$ for $\epsilon \leq |y| \leq R$, where $R> \epsilon >0$.

I assume that we have to multiply the reciprocal function by some kind of mollifier with compact support, but can't figure out the details. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is straightforward (and tedious) to find an even polynomial $p$ of degree 4 such that $p(\epsilon) = {1 \over \epsilon}$, $p'(\epsilon) = -{1 \over \epsilon^2}$ and $p''(\epsilon) = 2{1 \over \epsilon^3}$.

Define $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = \begin{cases} p(x), & |x| < \epsilon \\
{1 \over x}, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. It should be clear that $f$ is $C^2$ and $f$ is bounded (not that it matters, but it is bounded by $f(0)$).

Now let $\phi(x) = f(\|x\|)$.

It should be clear that $\phi$ is $C^2$ for $x \neq 0$, since the function $x \mapsto \|x\|$ is smooth for $x \neq 0$.

Since $p$ is even, we can write $p(x) = q(x^2)$ for some polynomial of degree 2, and so, if $\|x\| < \epsilon$, we can write
$\phi(x) = q(\|x\|^2)$, and since $x \mapsto q(\|x\|^2)$ is smooth everywhere we see that $\phi$ is $C^2$ everywhere.

If $\|x\| \ge \epsilon$, we have $\phi(x) = {1 \over \|x\|}$, hence we see that $\phi, \phi', \phi''$ are bounded for $\|x\| \ge \epsilon$. It follows by continuity that $\phi, \phi', \phi''$ are bounded everywhere.